# What kind of Layout is used in the Google application?

Tags: android

Does anyone know what kind of layout is used for the Google+ stream in the Android app? Is it a GridLayout or a custom layout?

I was trying a GridView for my application, but as far as I've found it's not possible to give items in a GridView a width of two columns, or am I missing something? Would GridLayout be an efficient way to display multiple (up to 50) Views?

Thanks!

Comment: Grid view is an vertially scrollable view. So u can not extend it horizontally.

Comment: You might consider posting some screenshots, annotating what specifically you are interested in. You may not be able to upload them here, as you are new to StackOverflow and need to have a certain karma level before you can upload images. But you could upload them elsewhere and link to them here.

Comment: Good Idea. I've uploaded a screenshot here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/179818/Screenshot%20Google.png. The part I'm interested in is below the ActionBar. It seems to be some kind of grid (GridLayout?) with some items taking up one cell and other taking up two cells (both horizontally and vertically).